Multiplying chains of matrices in JAX
Suppose I have a vector of parameters p which parameterizes a set of matrices A_1(p), A_2(p),...,A_N(p). I have a computation in which for some list of indices q of length M, I have to compute A_{q_M} * ... * A_{q_2} * A_{q_1} * v for several different q s. Each q has a different length, but crucially doesn't change! What changes, and what I wish to take gradients against is p.
I'm trying to figure out how to convert this to performant JAX. One way to do it is to have some large matrix Q which contains all the different qs on each row, padded out with identity matrices such that each multiplication chain is the same length, and then scan over a function that switch es between N different functions doing matrix-vector multiplications by A_n(p).
However -- I don't particularly like the idea of this padding. Also, since Q here is fixed, is there potentially a smarter way to do this? The distribution of lengths of q s has a very long tail, so Q will be dominated by padding.
EDIT: Here's a (edit 2: functional) minimal example
sigma0 = jnp.eye(2)
sigmax = jnp.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
sigmay = jnp.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]])
sigmaz = jnp.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]])
sigma = jnp.array([sigmax, sigmay, sigmaz])

def gates_func(params):
    theta = params["theta"]
    epsilon = params["epsilon"]

    n = jnp.array([jnp.cos(theta), 0, jnp.sin(theta)])
    omega = jnp.pi / 2 * (1 + epsilon)
    X90 = expm(-1j * omega * jnp.einsum("i,ijk->jk", n, sigma) / 2)

    return {
        "Z90": expm(-1j * jnp.pi / 2 * sigmaz / 2),
        "X90": X90
    }

def multiply_out(params):
    gate_lists = [["X90", "X90"], ["X90","Z90"], ["Z90", "X90"], ["X90","Z90","X90"]]

    gates = gates_func(params)
    out = jnp.zeros(len(gate_lists)) 
    
    for i, gate_list in enumerate(gate_lists):
        init = jnp.array([1.0,0.0], dtype=jnp.complex128)
        for g in gate_list:
            init = gates[g] @ init
        out = out.at[i].set(jnp.abs(init[0]))

    return out

params = dict(theta=-0.0, epsilon=0.001)
multiply_out(params)


I'm a bit lost reading your description of your code. Could you edit your question to add a minimal reproducible example?

Hi @jakevdp, I've added an example. Here gate_lists is Q, and params is p, and there return values of gates_func are the As

This of course isn't a fantastic example because it produces a gihugeous trace, but it's a starting point.

Your example has undefined variables (sigma and sigmaz, and maybe others). Also, is it deliberate that the for g in gate_list loop discards everything but the last iteration?

Ah sorry that was pretty sloppy. This includes all the necessary variables and moves the init definition outside they inner for g in gate_list since it's supposed to calculate jnp.abs((gate[..] @ gate[..] @ gate[...] @ init)[0]). Indeed it's intended to only take the last element of the final value of init since that's the final product of all the gates.

The main issue here is that JAX does not support string inputs. But you can use NumPy to manipulate string arrays and turn them into integer categorical arrays that can then be used by jax.jit and jax.vmap. The solution might look something like this:
import numpy as np

def gates_func_int(params, gate_list_vals):
  g = gates_func(params)
  identity = jnp.eye(*list(g.values())[0].shape)
  return jnp.stack([g.get(val, identity) for val in gate_list_vals])

@jax.jit
def multiply_out_2(params):
  # compile-time pre-processing
  gate_lists = [["X90", "X90"], ["X90","Z90"], ["Z90", "X90"], ["X90","Z90","X90"]]
  max_size = max(map(len, gate_lists))
  gate_array = np.array([gates + [''] * (max_size - len(gates))
                        for gates in gate_lists])
  gate_list_vals, gate_list_ints = np.unique(gate_array, return_inverse=True)
  gate_list_ints = gate_list_ints.reshape(gate_array.shape)

  # runtime computation
  gates = gates_func_int(params, gate_list_vals)[gate_list_ints]
  initial = jnp.array([[1.0],[0.0]], dtype=jnp.complex128)
  return jax.vmap(lambda g: jnp.abs(jnp.linalg.multi_dot([*g, initial]))[0])(gates).ravel()

multiply_out_2(params)


Thank you for the help! This is exactly the sort of assistance I was hoping for.

Actually sorry -- is there some way to get around the use of stacking identities? The length of the items in gate_lists is exponentially distributed, so it seems like this will create a lot of additional overhead multiplying by identity.

No, there's no way to get around this because of the SPMD requirement of vmap and other JAX transformations. If you don't want to stack identities, then your original nested for loops are probably the best you'll be able to do.

Is there some way to get the compiler to retain multiple traces? That is -- what if I bin gate_lists elements that are within a factor of 2 of each other and call them individually?

Yes, the compiler by default will cache multiple compilation artifacts. Your idea is one way that you might proceed.
